# Classic ASP page called from jQuery $.get won't decode line feeds

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I have a form containing a textarea on a page for a multi-line input that posts to a classic ASP script, which then loops through each line like this:

```
catlist = Split(request("catlist"),vbcrlf)
for i = 0 TO UBound(catList)
    'do some stuff to each line
next
```

This works fine when using an HTML POST or GET request.  But now I'm trying to redo the page containing the textarea to use jQuery $.get instead of a form, and it can't seem to handle the line feeds from the textarea.  Say the textarea contains:

```
test1
test2
```

Pressing the submit button executes this function:

```
function add() {
    var thetext = $("#thefield").val();
    $.get("task.asp", {action:"add",thetext:thetext});
}
```

That just crashes and gives me an unexpected token illegal (due to the line feeds - it works fine on a single line input).

So I make the function this instead:

```
function add() {
    var thetext = encodeURIComponent($("#thefield").val());
    $.get("task.asp", {action:"add",thetext:thetext});
}
```

This gets through without any script errors, but when I request("thetext") on the server side I only receive a single line containing:

> test1%0Atest2%0A

When I use regular Javascript (non-ajax) and submit a querystring using encodeURI I don't have to do any extra decryption on the server side, classic ASP has always handled it automatically.  But for some reason with this $.get method it's staying encoded.

Any way to make this work without changing the script on the server side to manual decode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%0A` is a linefeed

If you view text with linefeeds on windows it will look like 1 line.

so try changing your ASP to this

```
catlist = Split(request("catlist"),vblf)
```